# How to get UITextField's value into a NSString which is in UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield, nsstring

I set `UITextField` into `UITableViewCell`. Load the `UITableView` as per array count. All the textfields are editable. But, I want that, when I edit the `UITextField` then `UITextField` data should be stored into a predefined `NSString`. For each IndexPath.row's textfield is different string.

Attaching my code which I used to generate `NSMutableArray`...

```
[arrProfile removeAllObjects];
 arrProfile = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
              @{@"title": @"CUSTOMER NAME", @"details": strFName},
              @{@"title": @"EMAIL ID", @"details": strEmail},
              @{@"title": @"MOBILE NO.", @"details": strContact},
              @{@"title": @"STATE", @"details": strStateName},
              @{@"title": @"CITY", @"details": @""},
              nil];

[_tblProfile reloadData];
```

Now attaching code used in cellForRowAtIndexPath...

```
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cellProfile";

NSDictionary *dictProfile = [arrProfile objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
ProfileTableViewCell *cell = (ProfileTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

cell.lblTitle.text = [dictProfile objectForKey:@"title"];
cell.txtDetails.text = [dictProfile objectForKey:@"details"];

cell.txtDetails.delegate = self;
[self textFieldShouldReturn:cell.txtDetails];
[self textFieldShouldBeginEditing:cell.txtDetails];

return cell;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to build a dynamic form where a number of text fields will vary based on the array you are providing. You are trying to achieve this by taking table view and loading all text fields by each row. Now the problem comes up with how to take the value entered in each textfield. If this is your question here is the thing how to do it.

You can do this by using **Tag for textfield.** You heared it correct!. In tableview cell method give each textfield unique tag (you can use indexpath.row) for that purpose. Assign delegate here. Textfield delegate methods will be fired. Now from textfield delegate methods again based on tag get the input from the textfield as a string and store.

**Note:**

```
[self textFieldShouldReturn:cell.txtDetails];
[self textFieldShouldBeginEditing:cell.txtDetails];
```

Methods not required to call from tableview cellForRowAtIndexPath. Textfield delegate if you assign, it will take care of it.

Comment: it is not work if i didn't call textfield delegate in cellForRowAtIndex

Comment: I'm not saying to remove delegate. I'm saying calling of delegate methods not required. Here you are manually calling delegate methods. Delegate methods has to be fired by itself.

Comment: Thank you your suggestion is works my code is below into "Answer Your Question" button.

Comment: Great @AnupamDas

Answer (score 1):

```
cell.txtDetails.delegate = self;
cell.txtDetails.tag = indexPath.row;
[cell.txtDetails addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidEndEditing:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];



-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    if (textField.tag == 0) {
        strFName = textField.text;
    } else if (textField.tag == 2) {
        strContact = textField.text;
    }
    [self loadTheMainArray];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:**

That fits your implementation
Assign cell index to `txtDetails.tag` while creating cell row (`cellForRowAtIndexPath`).
This will help you in identifying your text field row

```
txtDetails.tag = indexPath.row
```

Implement UITextField delegate `textFieldDidEndEditing` OR `shouldChangeCharactersIn` to

1. Get the field value.
2. And row index

   arrProfile[textField.tag] = "new value"

**Option 2:**

Define a protocol to get cell text updates

```
protocol  MYCellDelegate: class {
    textFieldDidChange(row: Int, string: String)
}

class MyCell: UITableViewCell {
    weak var delegate:  MYCellDelegate?
    var row: Int
}
```

In your cellForRowAtIndexPath do following

```
cell.delegate = self
cell.row = indexPath.row
```

Implement UITextFieldDelegate in cell (`textFieldDidEndEditing` OR `shouldChangeCharactersIn`)

and call `textFieldDidChange(row: Int, string: String)` with appropriate values

Don't forget to remove following lines from `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
[self textFieldShouldReturn:cell.txtDetails];
[self textFieldShouldBeginEditing:cell.txtDetails];
```

Answer (score 0):

1.you can try use block function add to cell,but now follows a code block:

```
cell.m_textChangeBlock = ^(NSString *text) {
    if(indexPath.row){
        weakSelf.m_models[indexPath.section].rtext = text;
    }else{
        weakSelf.m_models[indexPath.section].ltext = text;
    }
};
```